# Pourquoi un "x" aux adjectifs type "curieux", "joyeux", "impérieux"

Tags: grammaire, expressions, adjectifs, pluriel, lexique

Je suis en pleine relecture de mes cours de lexicologie, et je me posais une question : pourquoi les adjectifs comme « curieux », « joyeux », « vicieux »... prennent un ***x*** au masculin singulier ?

J'ai cherché du côté de leur étymologie et je n'ai pas trouvé de ressemblance marquante qui aurait pu expliquer cela.

Comment: Peux-tu préciser si ce que tu trouves curieux est le fait qu'ils prennent un *x* en tant que marque du pluriel ou le fait qu'au singulier ils semblent prendre la marque du pluriel ?

Comment: C'est effectivement que ces adjectifs semblent prendre la marque du pluriel au singulier masculin ! Je note qu'il s'agit bien d'un morphogramme qui marque simplement ce masculin, mais je n'explique pas d'où il vient !

Comment: Vu! Bon alors... je répondrai mais un peu plus tard... il faut d'abord que je me mette... au *régime* ;-)

Comment: Haha, c'est parfait (tout comme ce trait d'esprit ;-) ) ! Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 8):

Quelques précisions paléographiques: ce ⟨x⟩ a la même source que celui de *je veux*, d'*eux*, de *mieux* ou de *chevaux*. Alignés ainsi, on se rend facilement compte de l'absence de lien systématique entre un ⟨ux⟩ final et la marque orthographique du pluriel.

L'origine de cette graphie est bien connue: les suffixes -us et -os si fréquents dans les textes latins se sont vus remplacés par une série d’abréviations dans les manuscrits de l'antiquité à l'invention de la presse mécanique. Les plus communes étaient ⟨ꝰ⟩ et ⟨;⟩ (du moins dans les textes carolingiens que j'ai étudié), mais on trouvait également ⟨x⟩ dans ce rôle (quoique plus rarement).

Une fois qu'on a commencé à écrire en français, toutes les abréviations scribales de ce genre ont été appliquées au français, là où il était possible de les appliquer (le ⟨ç⟩ est une survivance moderne de ce processus). Le vieux français ne regorgeait pas vraiment de -u finaux, mais l'évolution de la langue va en fournir deux sources: les /l/ et /λ/ devenus voyelle devant consonne (comme dans chevals /t͡ʃəvals/ -> chevaus /t͡ʃəvaʊ̯s/, bails /baλs/ -> baus /baʊ̯s/ ou els /els/ -> eus /eʊ̯s/) et les /o/ et /ɔ/ devenus diphtongues puis /ø/ en syllable ouverte accentuée (c'est le cas du suffixe -ōsum /'o:.sum/, qui devient /ozʊ/ en latin vulgaire puis /eʊ̯s/ en ancien français).

L'abréviation qui s'impose dans ces cas-là en français, jusqu'au 12<sup>e</sup> siècle, c'est justement ⟨x⟩. On écrit donc souvent, ⟨chevax⟩ ⟨bax⟩, à coté de de ⟨chevaus⟩ et de ⟨bails⟩, ou de ⟨chevalz⟩ et de ⟨bailz⟩. L'orthographe des diphtongues susmentionnées est plus complexe, on rencontre tantôt ⟨o⟩, tantôt ⟨u⟩, ⟨ou⟩, ⟨eu⟩, ⟨ue⟩, ⟨oe⟩ ou ⟨u⟩. C'est finalement ⟨eu⟩ qui l'emportera, mais de manière plus tardive, au 14<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Au 13<sup>e</sup> siècle, l'usage commence à changer et les scribes associent les différentes graphies pour créer les hybrides tels que ⟨alx⟩, ⟨aulx⟩/⟨eulx⟩ et ⟨aux⟩/⟨eux⟩, dont nous avons hérités et où x a rejoint s et z comme représentation du /s/ final. Par example, [un manuscrit de la *Queste del saint Graal* (daté des environs de 1225-1230)](http://txm.ish-lyon.cnrs.fr/bfm/pdf/qgraal_cm_2019-07.pdf) orthographie le cas sujet de son Graal titulaire ⟨Graax⟩ 10 fois, ⟨Graalx⟩ 4 fois et ⟨Graaux⟩ 4 fois. Toutes ces formes restent bien entendu en compétition jusqu'à une date plus tardive (j'ai retrouvé en recherchant cette question un ⟨amourex⟩ de la moitié du 16<sup>e</sup>).

Pour en revenir au suffixe -eux, sa graphie représente donc étymologiquement la suite de la voyelle /ø/ suivi de la consonne /s/, que l'on retrouve toujours (sans dévoisement final du /z/ resté intervocalique) dans son féminin -euse. Ce /s/ fait partie du suffixe et n'a jamais été la marque du pluriel.

Tous les ⟨ux⟩ finaux n'ont pas cette justification étymologique, celui de *vieux* m. sg., par example, est dû à une contamination de sa prononciation par celle de son pluriel. Seule la forme de liaison, vieil, préserve l'orthographe et la prononciation originelle. En toute logique, *vieux* devrait s'écrire ⟨vieu⟩, mais à l'emprunt de la prononciation du pluriel s'est ajouté celui de son orthographe.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour ces précisions. Étant tout de même noté la fréquence des *chevaLX* je crois qu'il vaudrait mieux l'exclure de votre liste d'exemples.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer** :

- Curieux vient du latin curiosus radical cur/suffixe **iosus**
- Impérieux vient du latin imperiosus radical imper/suffixe **iosus**
- Joyeux, moins évident suivant le chemin par lequel on remonte, mêne soit à un *gaud -iosus* qui n'existe pas vraiment en latin soit à un très légitime *jocosus* mais cela ne change pas... le suffixe.

**(i)osus** est un suffixe latin très utilisé pour la formation des adjectifs dérivés de substantifs. Repris à l'identique dans le gallo-roman, il évoluera vers le français en (*i)ous* puis *(i)eus* ou (*i)ieux* selon la typo qui nous reste en finale au masculin.
La forme féminine suit le même chemin épargné par le quirck typographique *(i)euse*.

---

**TL;DR**

Un **s** ou **x** en finale d'un mot masculin n'est pas comme souvent en français moderne la marque du pluriel.
Au XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle (période où la formation d'adjectifs en *-eux* a été la plus féconde) de nombreux copistes de manuscrits du XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle s'y sont trompés.

Au XIII<sup>e</sup> et avant, un **s** (ou **x**) final est très souvent **la marque du sujet** !
Quand le français emprunte un mot au latin, il intègre dans son lexique le nominatif. Pour le masculin donc... le plus souvent... une terminaison en *-us*.

Mais si le français ancien ne reprend pas les déclinaisons latines, il distingue morphologiquement le sujet des compléments. Le sujet du *régime* (le plus souvent complément d'objet). Pas de **s** en finale d'accusatif de la seconde déclinaison ⇒ Exit la finale s au régime.

Ainsi le *populus* → *peuples* en tant que sujet singulier et *peuple* en tant que régime singulier.
Il en ira de même avec les adjectifs épithètes *grandus* → *grans* en épithète du sujet et *gran* (voire *grant*) en épithète du régime.

Comment: pour être plus exact, le *x* était à l'époque l'abbréviation de -us dans les manuscrit. Lorsque l'habitude a été prises d'écrire à nouveau les -u "disparus", les -x sont restés.

Comment: @Circeus : La longue histoire des *cheva **l x** peut laisser penser que c'est un poil plus complexe que cela. Aussi, après m'être assuré dans l'OP que ce n'était pas là sa préoccupation... j'ai balancé le tout en typo problème. voire un *quirck*...

Comment: quirk  : [accident]   bizarrerie, caprice. Pourquoi « quirck » (pas une orthographe  alternative en anglais) ?

Comment: @LPH : Parce qu'il devient ainsi autoqualificatif.Je n'aime pas les nonautoqualificatifs car je ne sais pas dire ce qu'ils sont.

Comment: Comme je ne connais pas le terme « autoqualificatif », ni n'en trouve une définition je suppose que vous voulez dire par là « particularisé » ; je dois donc conclure aussi que ce nouveau terme est entièrement dû, pour son orthographe du moins, à votre initiative.